# macos nanosleep() sleeping for (far) too long

Tags: macos, posix, grand-central-dispatch, usleep

Conceptually I run following Swift pseudo code to regulate UDP sent data bitrate

```
let sendQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "_send_queue", qos: .userInitiated)
sendQueue.async {
    for data in datas {
        socket.send(data)

        if let timespec = getTimeToSleep() {
            var ts = timespec
            nanosleep(&ts, nil) 
        }
    }
}
```

In my case time talculated to sleep is usually about 0.001s. In general the real spent in `nanosleep()` is a couple of percent higher. So far so good - but after some time `nanosleep()` return after MUCH longer time - easily it's seconds or even a minute. I'm pretty sure I do not request such a long interval. I tried following with no result

- build the app with `release` config
- ran the app outside debugger

What is strange that if this happens while ran from debugger - when I pause and resume the app it runs fine again for a while.

Any clues?

Comment: You are blocking inside an async block which is an anto pattern

Comment: Just made more testing: I even removed `socket.send()` so at the end I only call `nanosleep` in a loop. Same result.

Comment: Edit your question to show a minimal example of the behavior you encounter. Your current question seems to ask if there's a bug in `nanosleep`

Answer (score 2):

Ah, found the reason for this behavior. The macOS app nap is causing this.

Executing

```
serverActivity = ProcessInfo().beginActivity(options: ProcessInfo.ActivityOptions.userInitiated, reason: "Serving Fast Data")
```

before I start to serve UDP data makes all stable in time and neat.